# Rails is generating wrong path on nested resources with Polymorphic_url and STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a not so traditional code and i'm struggling to generate the correct path for a resource.

In my routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :matches do
    resources :lineups do
      resources :substitutions
    end
  end
end
```

My models are:

Match.rb

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :home_lineup
  has_one :away_lineup
end
```

On home_lineup.rb for the STI structure

```
class HomeLineup < Lineup

end
```

On away_lineup.rb for the STI structure

```
class AwayLineup < Lineup

end
```

lineup.rb

```
class Lineup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :match
  #has a :type column as :string
end
```

and, substitution.rb

```
class Substitution < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lineup
end
```

When I try to:

```
m = Match.last
l = m.home_lineup
s = Substitution.new
app.polymorphic_url([:admin, m, l, s])
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `admin_match_away_lineup_substitutions_url' for #<ActionDispatch::Integration::Session:0x000055f4327a60d0>)
Did you mean?  admin_match_lineup_substitutions_url
               admin_match_lineup_substitution_url
               admin_match_lineup_substitution_path
               admin_match_lineup_substitutions_path
```

But what I really wanted is "admin_match_lineup_...".

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: How are `HomeLineup` and `AwayLineup` different?

Comment: Hi, Jvillian. They are actually the same. I used that structure to have two different relationship with the Lineup model, but without the belong_to on the Match model.

Comment: Why didn't you do `has_one :home_lineup, class_name: 'LineUp'` instead? That would, IMO, be the more conventional approach and eliminate the heartache you are suffering by doing things unconventionally.

Comment: Good question. Lol.

Comment: I'm not home right know, but I'll try later. Thanks.

Comment: Jvillian, I have tried as you suggested and it works for the polymorphic_url. However, as I had two has_one relationship, without STI rails could not figure out with Lineup was the 'home' or 'away'.
Anyways I found a solution that work for me, and I will post bellow.
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem in this blog post (http://leomayleomay.github.io/blog/2014/03/24/customize-the-polymorphic-url-for-sti/).

To force Lineup to respond the correct name add this code on it`s file:

lineup.rb

```
def self.model_name
  ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Lineup")
end
```

Thanks and happy coding.